# Cannot read property 'prefix' of null discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

> Hello, I had this problem like 1 week ago, and still can't solve it. So, I'm trying to do per-server prefixes, but when I boot up the bot, it sends the boot-up confirmation message, but then it says the error and it shuts down. Here is the error:

```
                guildPrefixes[guildId] = result.prefix
                                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefix' of null
```

> I can't see anything wrong here, but anyways, here is the code:

```
module.exports.loadPrefixes = async (client) => {
    await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
        try {
            for (const guild of client.guilds.cache) {
                const guildId = guild[1].id
                const guildPrefixes = {}

                const result = await commandPrefixSchema.findOne({_id: guildId})
                guildPrefixes[guildId] = result?.prefix || dprefix
                console.log(result)
            }

            console.log('[INFO] Prefixes have been loaded')
        } finally {
            mongoose.connection.close()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you console.log `result`? It seems like the property `prefix` doesn't exist

Comment: I get this: [INFO] Bot is online
[INFO] Connected to MongoDB
null
null
null
null
{ _id: '853629920722681856', __v: 0, prefix: '!' }
[INFO] Prefixes have been loaded

The confusing part is that it says like null 4 times

Comment: The thing is, i needed to remove the .prefix part for that to work. But now when i do a command, it doesn't work, because the prefix is not defined

The .prefix part was for it to know it was the prefix, but it just doesn't work when i put it again

Comment: It seems like the first 4 elements in your loop (client.guilds.cache) cannot be found in your DB hence the `null`, only the last one returns a result.

Comment: wdym? sorry, i'm new to coding. So idk what you mean

Comment: Try setting `guildPrefixes[guildId] = result` and then get the prefix by doing something like `let prefix = result[prefix];`

Comment: You're looping over an array of guilds and find them in your database based on their `guildId`. But the first 4 times it returns `null` because it cannot find a result. Since `null` does not have a property called `prefix` it crashes.

Comment: ok i will try that, thanks!

Comment: Consider putting that after your `for` loop as well based off of what @Reyno said.

Comment: oh Reyno now i understand

Comment: You can prevent this by using a `if` statement or by providing a fallback like `guildPrefixes[guildId] = result?.prefix || '!'`. Which means it tries to use the value it finds, if it doesn't exist use a `!`

Comment: ok, but i did that already at the top (i haven't showed you) but i will do that

Comment: ok, erm, i tried what you have said. the bot boots up fine, but the commands doesn't work.

Comment: here is my new code
`module.exports.loadPrefixes = async (client) => {
    await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
        try {
            for (const guild of client.guilds.cache) {
                const guildId = guild[1].id
                const guildPrefixes = {}

                const result = await commandPrefixSchema.findOne({_id: guildId})
                guildPrefixes[guildId] = result?.prefix || dprefix
            }

            console.log('[INFO] Prefixes have been loaded')
        } finally {
            mongoose.connection.close()
        }
    })
}`

Comment: Instead of putting your code into your comment, you should edit your question instead to show the new code.

Comment: ok i will do it now

Comment: edited, you can see now